# Masking Long Code in MobileConnect

Tags: mobileconnect

If we mask the Long Code with a From Name and send the SMS to a customer, and the customer wants to respond back to unsubscribe, then will we need to add the Long Code explicitly in the SMS e.g. To Unsubscribe send STOP to Long Code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you send masked as a from name, then in order for the customer to be able to respond back, you will need to detail the instruction in the message body i.e. reply Stop to 0123456789

Though a customer can reply to the code in such manner, the obvious downside to the long code is the character length it takes up in the message body and the customer exoerience

Using a Short Code is that bit friendlier.

Depending on the country being sent to, you could refer the customer to a preference center URL (bit.ly URL) but the legislation varies per country.

Also per country, you don't necessarily need a stop message on every text - it does need to be on the first message sent to customer but not necessarily all messages. You will need to check the legislation for the country you are sending to